# Is it possible to exclude appendix slides of the total number of slides?

Tags: quarto

In the example below, I have 3 slides: main content, appendix title and appendix content. However, I'd like to exclude the two appendix slides from the total count on the bottom right.

The expected output is to have `1/1` on the bottom right. How can I do that?

```
---
format: 
  revealjs:
    slide-number: true
---

Slide with main content

# Appendix {.appendix}

---

Slide with appendix content
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4798): the solution is to write a Lua filter to automatically apply `visibility="uncounted"` to all slides in the "Appendix" section.

custom.lua

```lua
local in_appendix = false

Header = function(h)
  if h.level == 1 then
    if h.classes:includes("appendix") then
      in_appendix = true
      h.attributes["visibility"] = "uncounted"
    else
      in_appendix = false
    end
  end
  if h.level == 2 and in_appendix then
    h.attributes["visibility"] = "uncounted"
  end
  return h
end
```

```
---
format: 
  revealjs:
    slide-number: true
    filters: [custom.lua]
---

Slide with main content

# Appendix {.appendix}

##

Slide with appendix content

##

Another slide with appendix content
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this want you want?

```
---
format: 
  revealjs:
    slide-number: true
---

Slide with main content

# Appendix {.appendix visibility="uncounted"}


## {visibility="uncounted"}


Slide with appendix content
```

Comment: Ideally I would like that `visibility="uncounted"` applies to all slides in the appendix section without having to rewrite it on each slide, but yes the output is what I want

Comment: I tried wrapping the uncounted part in a div, but this did not work. You may need some specific js function for this.